# Read a PDF file with pure javascript without using any api

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to read the content of pdf file using javascript without using any apis or jquery.
I dont want to use pdf.js

Comment: You can watch how pdf.js implemented - and try it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

an alternative to `pdf.js` then you can try using `pdfreader` is good alternate, 
package.json make entry for `pdfreader` and below code to read file providing path to pdf file,

```
var Reader = require("pdfreader").PdfReader;
new Reader().parseFileItems("pdf-file", function(err, item){
  if (item && item.text)
    item.text // Use Text data here
});
```